# Как по номеру понимать приблизительное местоположение пользователя?

Tags: python

Всем привет, делаю приложение на питоне, встала задача определять приблизительное местоположение по номеру телефона. Есть ли какая-то библиотека на питоне для этого или какие-то может методы разбора ?

Comment: никак, какое отношение номер телефона имеет к геолокации ?

Comment: Если телефон стационарный - код города. Если сотовый, то никак. Раньше можно было по мобильному номеру определить регион, теперь уже нет.

Comment: Для этого (в случае сотового телефона) нужен доступ к [VLR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_GSM) провайдера. (да, библиотеки (по крайней мере самописные) на питоне для этого есть, но скорее всего это вам не поможет)

Comment: Нет, ну если допустить, что мало пока кто перешёл со своим номером к другому оператору, то можно регион прикинуть

Comment: Мне нужно при введенном номере говорить пользователю какой страны это номер и к какому региону принадлежит, данная фишка есть в современных смартфонах

Comment: так там разве по номеру определяют ? посмотрите разрешения для этого приложения, 100% там будут геоданные или жпрс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил свою проблему с помощью библиотеки: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Answer (score 2):

Данные о геопозиционировании сотового терминала подключенного к той или инной базовой станции доступны только оператору, получить их не получится - разве что для своего номера при личном запросе провайдеру сотовой связи. Касательно страны происхождения то тут немного проще, у каждого оператора есть номерной ресурс с кодом страны и т.д.,эта информация уже в свободном доступе, конкретный регион для мобильного номера определить не получится, это возможно только для прямых городских номеров у которых есть код города.

Answer (score 1):

[есть сервис](https://htmlweb.ru/) . Не бесплатный но не дорогой. 5000 зпросов 250р.
отдает по запросу [http://htmlweb.ru/geo/api.php?telcod=НОМЕР_ТЕЛЕФОНА&json&charset=utf-8&api_key=xxxx](http://htmlweb.ru/geo/api.php?telcod=%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0_%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A4%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%90&json&charset=utf-8&api_key=xxxx) json, xml или html
Ну к примеру так...

```
{   'country_id':'RU',
    'country':'Россия',
    'region_id':49,
    'region':'Ростовская область',
    'okrug':'Южный федеральный округ',
    'rajon_id':0,
    'rajon':'',
    'city_id':1711,
    'city':'Ростов-на-Дону',
    'oper':'',
    'oper_id':0,
    'limit':50
}
```

Это краткий вывод